# Reusing computed columns in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I reuse a computed column in SQL in MySQL?
Say: my query is something like: -

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT_TZ(
        if(timestamp_start > last_update, timestamp_start, last_update), 
        'GMT', 
        user.timezone
    ) as time_usr_tz
from 
    shecdule
    inner join user on shecdule.user_id = user.user_id
where 
    CONVERT_TZ(
        if(timestamp_start > last_update, timestamp_start, last_update), 
        'GMT', 
        user.timezone
    )
    < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
```

If you see the query the "CONVERT_TZ....." part is repeated.

This is only a sample query. Actually, I have to use that computed column several times. 
So if I make change in one place, I have to change in many places.
And the size of the query becomes scary, too.

Is there any way to avoid such duplication?

**UPDATE**
I already have sub-query in my original query, so sub-query is not a preferable option. Is it possible in any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  ctz
FROM    (
        SELECT  shecdule.*,
                CONVERT_TZ(
                if(timestamp_start > last_update, timestamp_start, last_update), 
                'GMT', 
                user.timezone
                ) AS ctz
        FROM    shecdule
        INNER JOIN
                user
        ON      user.user_id = s.user_id
        ) s
WHERE  ctz < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

Note that this query doesn't use the indexes on `timestamp_start` and `last_update` efficiently.

See the performance details in the article in my blog:

- [**Selecting timestamps for a time zone**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/25/selecting-timestamps-for-a-time-zone/)

In two words, you better use this:

```
SELECT  ctz
FROM    (
        SELECT  shecdule.*,
                CONVERT_TZ(
                if(timestamp_start > last_update, timestamp_start, last_update), 
                'GMT', 
                user.timezone
                ) AS ctz
        FROM    shecdule
        INNER JOIN
                user
        ON      user.user_id = s.user_id
        WHERE   timestamp_start < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() + INTERVAL 14 HOUR
                OR last_update < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() + INTERVAL 14 HOUR
        ) s
WHERE  ctz < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

This inner query will perform coarse filtering on `timestamp_start` and `last_update`  using indexes (no zone conversion can offset the time more than `+14:00` hours from `UTC`).

The outer subquery will then fine filter the results based on user's time zone.

If you don't like subqueries, you may also use:

```
SELECT  shecdule.*,
        CONVERT_TZ(
        if(timestamp_start > last_update, timestamp_start, last_update), 
        'GMT', 
        user.timezone
        ) AS ctz
FROM    shecdule
INNER JOIN
       user
ON      user.user_id = s.user_id
/* 
        WHERE   timestamp_start < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() + INTERVAL 14 HOUR
                OR last_update < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() + INTERVAL 14 HOUR
*/
HAVING  ctz < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```